# Why are multiple paths being selecting in inkspape when I click on one

Tags: inkscape, path, selections

I have two paths that do not appear to have any intersections but if I select one of the other they both get selected. Is this because they touch somewhere or is there a way to "link" paths that I am not aware of?

[image: Paths in question]

Here is a screen capture of the same thing https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbyoi.jpg

Comment: That would *appear* to be a *compound shape* -- i.e. a shape with a "hole" in it. So when you click one, you select the entire shape with it's hole.

Comment: I see, aside from zooming and and searching the entire path is there a way to locate the hole?

Comment: the hole will be the inner path. I'm not an inkscape user. Perhaps someone will come along and explain based on that application usage.

Answer (score 4):

With the paths selected as in the image, click Path, Break Apart. If that doesn't split them into individual paths and objects, I'll be surprised, but you would then use the Ungroup option. Both (or more) paths will remain selected, but you'll see marquee boxes in more than one location after the break apart action.